# How to send a post request to Azure IoT Hub using postman

Tags: azure, postman, azure-iot-hub

I am trying, in order to simulate a device, to send a message to an existing IoT-Hub following this procedure: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1113447/Azure-IOT-Hub-REST-API

I am able to successfully create my shared access signature using the Device Explorer.

In postman, I send a post request to:
`https://myHubName.azure-devices.net/devices/myDeviceId/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03`
(my real hub name isn't myHubName)

With the Authorization header with the shared access signature and with the content type header,

With this JSON: `{deviceId: "myDeviceId", temperature: "80"}`

But I have no response whatsoever from the endpoint (Timeout).

I feel like the server should at least respond with an unauthorized request. Am I missing something here?

---

**EDIT:**
As discussed with Rita, I was missing the s in https when I was trying to send the request. The IoT-Hub now responds appropriately.

Comment: Your code works for me. What's format of your shared access signature?

Comment: This is what the SAS looks like : SharedAccessSignature sr=HOSTNAME.azure-devices.net&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxh4T9R%2BGLVt9jFFc35Y%3D&se=1525xxxxxx&skn=iothubowner


Also, just stating the obvious here, but the IoT-hub is active in azure.

Comment: Can you monitor your device event data in the Device Explorer? Or can you [send event to your device using SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted#create-a-simulated-device-app)?

Comment: I am able to send and monitor the data that is produced from the SimulatedDevice example in the tutorial. All by using the same endpoint http://i.imgur.com/awZHgfH.png (it was at 0 before launching the SimulatedDevice program)

Comment: What's the status code in postman after posting the request?

Comment: There is just no response from the server.  I tried from three different internet connections without success. http://i.imgur.com/3ZPaqLi.png I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143928/discussion-between-moncefmd-and-rita-han-msft).